# Distorting a 2D image with a rig?

Tags: armature, bones

I have a 2D image broken up into separate layers (upper arm,forearm,hand etc.), and have positioned the bones. When I test them in Pose Mode several things go wrong. As I rotate  some limbs get fatter, while others will stick along one edge, and the limb distorts badly. Nothing can move the edge.
I have only parented each limb to each bone, should I also have e.g. parented foot to lower leg and lower leg to upper leg and that to body?

Comment: It's hard to tell with the current information. Can you elaborate more? Post images of how you rigged your object and the deformation you are getting. You'll get better answers if you post your .blend file

Comment: Very hard to diagnose something that is visual with only a text description, images or blend files are appreciated.

Comment: With each part as a separate image you only need to parent each plane to a single bone, sounds more like you parented to armature with auto-weights.